# Spring-data-jpa repository query keywords "In" is not working with openJPA version 2.3.0 or later

Tags: jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, openjpa, spring-orm

Modified:

I have modified the title for more specified.

After verified, the problem is the repository query keywords "In" is not working when we used openJPA lib version 2.3.0 or later.

The original lib dependencies which were worked fine are as below

```
openjpa: 2.2.2
Spring framework(orm, test, context, etc..): 4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-data-jpa: 1.3.0.RELEASE
postgres-jdbc: 9.4-1201-jdbc41
jdk: 1.7
```

If the openjpa has been upgraded to 2.3.0, 2.4.0 or 2.4.1, the query keywords "In" will always stick in the parameter which given at the very first time.

Even we have upgraded all possibly related libs to the latest version is still not working. Whatever with jdk 1.7 or 1.8(Use corresponding postgreSQL jdbc driver)

```
openjpa: 2.4.1
Spring framework(orm, test, context, etc..): 4.3.0.RELEASE
spring-data-jpa: 1.10.2.RELEASE
postgres-jdbc: 9.4.1208
jdk: 1.8
```

---

Update:

It looks like the repository query keywords `In` has problem here.

We have tried to testing findByDeviceId as below code which only findBy instead of findByIn

```
        List<Subtask> subtasks = this.subtaskDao.findByDeviceId("1000000002");
        print(subtasks);
        List<Subtask> subtasks1 = this.subtaskDao.findByDeviceId("1000000003");
        print(subtasks1);
        List<Subtask> subtasks2 = this.subtaskDao.findByDeviceId("1000000004");
        print(subtasks2);enter code here
```

It works fine. The result is correct.

And we also tried to using JPQL of the repository interface as below which uses @Query annotation to do query.

```
@Query("SELECT entity FROM Subtask as entity WHERE entity.deviceId IN :deviceIdList AND entity.state IN :states")
public List<Subtask> findByDeviceIdInAndStateInOrderByIdAsc(@Param("deviceIdList") Collection<String> deviceIdList, @Param("states")  Collection<Integer> states);
```

In this way, the result also is correct even that the parameter is a List.

So, the result will be incorrect only if we used findBy something In query method.

The DaoBase interface as follows

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface DaoBase<T extends EntityBase, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<T>
{}
```

What happened to the repository query keywords `In` of openJPA version 2.3.0?

---

Says we have a DAO interface subtask as below

```
public interface SubtaskDao extends DaoBase<Subtask, Long>
{
    public List<Subtask> findByDeviceIdInAndStateInOrderByIdAsc(Collection<String> deviceIdList, Collection<Integer> states);
}
```

And junit test as follows

```
List<Subtask> subtasks = this.subtaskDao.findByDeviceIdInAndStateInOrderByIdAsc(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"1000000002"}), Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{5,10}));
System.out.println("1" + subtasks);
print(subtasks);
List<Subtask> subtasks1 = this.subtaskDao.findByDeviceIdInAndStateInOrderByIdAsc(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"1000000003"}), Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{5,10}));
System.out.println("2" + subtasks1);
print(subtasks1);
List<Subtask> subtasks2 = this.subtaskDao.findByDeviceIdInAndStateInOrderByIdAsc(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"1000000004"}), Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{5,10}));
System.out.println("3" + subtasks2);
print(subtasks2);

private void print(List<Subtask> subtasks)
{
    for (Subtask subtask : subtasks)
    {
        System.out.println(subtask.getId() + ", " + subtask.getDeviceId());
    }
}
```

The result will be correct as below when we used openJPA version 2.2.2 and spring-data-jpa version 1.3.0.RELEASE

```
1[devicemanage.repository.appdeploy.entity.Subtask@3b01897f, devicemanage.repository.appdeploy.entity.Subtask@6b3b2c34]
444, 1000000002
2[devicemanage.repository.appdeploy.entity.Subtask@4377ed24, devicemanage.repository.appdeploy.entity.Subtask@7a30e30b]
447, 1000000003
449, 1000000003
3[devicemanage.repository.appdeploy.entity.Subtask@b339a08, devicemanage.repository.appdeploy.entity.Subtask@1d556461]
410, 1000000004
```

But when we have upgraded the openJPA lib to version 2.3.0 or later(2.4.0 or 2.4.1). The result will become incorrect as follows

```
1[devicemanage.repository.appdeploy.entity.Subtask@77a9ac36, devicemanage.repository.appdeploy.entity.Subtask@3c743d40]
444, 1000000002
2[devicemanage.repository.appdeploy.entity.Subtask@3a5ce4b8, devicemanage.repository.appdeploy.entity.Subtask@38848217]
444, 1000000002
3[devicemanage.repository.appdeploy.entity.Subtask@511d5e6e, devicemanage.repository.appdeploy.entity.Subtask@7a78d380]
444, 1000000002
```

It looks like each `findByDeviceIdInAndStateInOrderByIdAsc` has given a parameter deviceIdList `Array.asList(new String [] {"1000000002"})`, so that every finding results are the subtask of device `1000000002`.

The DB is postgreSQL 9.4 windows version and the JDBC driver is as below

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</version>
        </dependency>
```

Is there anything we have missed?

Comment: It seems you might be missing a step here, or something not shared with the readers.  Where does the implementation of this interface come from?

Comment: Hi @JohnAment, thanks for the reply. I have updated the DaoBase interface in my question. But there is no implementation of the SubtaskDao interface. It is query method of Spring-data-jpa http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods